# Trying to use drawString method to print a name

Tags: java, graphics, drawstring

I'm just going through some basic tutorials at the moment.  The current one wants a graphics program that draws your name in red.  I've tried to make a NameComponent Class which extends JComponent, and uses the drawString() method to do this:

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class NameComponent extends JComponent {

    public void paintMessage(Graphics g) {

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    g2.setColor(Color.RED);
    g2.drawString("John", 5, 175);

    }
}
```

and use a NameViewer Class which makes use of JFrame to display the name:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class NameViewer {

public static void main (String[] args) {

    JFrame myFrame = new JFrame();
    myFrame.setSize(400, 200);
    myFrame.setTitle("Name Viewer");
    myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    NameComponent myName = new NameComponent();
    myFrame.add(myName);

    myFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

...but when I run it, the frame comes up blank!  Could anyone let me know what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the method `paintComponent` rather than `paintMessage`. Adding the `@Override` annotation over the method will show that `paintMessage` is not a standard method of `JComponent`. Also you may want to reduce the y-coordinate in your `drawString` as the text is currently not visible due to the additional decoration dimensions of the `JFrame`. Finally remember to call `super.paintComponent` to repaint the background of the component.

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
   super.paintComponent(g);
   Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
   g2.setColor(Color.RED);
   g2.drawString("John", 5, 100);
}
```

See: [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this line after `public void paintMessage(Graphics g){` :

`super.paint(g);`

This tells Java to use the superclass (JComponent) to paint the message.

You will also need to call your method `paintComponents()` rather than `paintMessage()`

Comment: no problem. just remember to upvote good answers and accept best answer (hint, hint)